# how to change url in htaccess for two php files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am dont know mutch about .htaccess. I need help here. I have this code in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pro_detail.php?client=$1 [PT]
```

which changes

```
http://xyx.pk/abc/pro_detail.php?client=umair
```

to

```
http://xyz.pk/abc/umair
```

now I need change

```
http://xyz.pk/abc/project_detail.php?project=dreamhousing
```

to

```
http://xyz.pk/abc/dreamhousing
```

please help.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This url scheme will not work. Because .htaccess rules have no idea which text belongs to project or which text belongs to client. It'll always match the first rule. Its better you prefix `project/` or `client/`. This way they can be mapped correctly. So use this,

```
RewriteRule ^client/(.*)$ pro_detail.php?client=$1 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^project/(.*)$ project_detail.php?project=$1 [L,PT]
```

This will allow `http://xyz.pk/abc/project/dreamhousing` to map `http://xyz.pk/abc/project_detail.php?project=dreamhousing`

Comment: thanks, yes its working . but one thing i need is xyz.pk/abc/project/dreamhousing should be like xyz.pk/dreamhousing

Comment: Sorry dear. you helped me . your answer worked for me. thank you so much